# How can I use the DataTemplateKey in a metro app

Tags: xaml, microsoft-metro

The new Windows 8 metro API still defineds class DataTemplateKey.

However, I can figure out how to use it.

Do you have an example in XAML that shows how it can be used?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example on how to use DataTemplateKey. Just a note and a reminder : **The x:Key attribute will take precedence over the automatic DataTemplateKey that is generated based on the DataType**

```
<Window.Resources>
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Red" />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="SelectedTemplate">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="White" />
</DataTemplate>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" x:Key="ContainerStyle">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource SelectedTemplate}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

</Window.Resources>
<ListBox x:Name="lstItems" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContainerStyle}" />
```